# Why is the highlighted area where D is constant is not considered in this Karnaugh map?

Tags: boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

Here is a link to the K map: http://tma.main.jp/logic/logic.php?lang=en&type=eq&eq=%28%7EA%7EBC%7ED%29+%2B+%28%7EA%7EBCD%29+%2B+%28%7EAB%7ECD%29+%2B+%28%7EABCD%29+%2B+%28A%7EB%7EC%7ED%29+%2B+%28A%7EB%7ECD%29+%2B+%28A%7EBC%7ED%29+%2B+%28A%7EBCD%29+%2B+%28AB%7EC%7ED%29+%2B+%28AB%7ECD%29+%2B+%28ABC%7ED%29+%2B+%28ABCD%29

I've also attached the screenshot below.
[image: K Map]

My questions is, if the groups should be large enough, why the highlighted area is not considered but only a subset is considered to get BD instead of D?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The groups should be "large enough" so they cancel a variable `X` and `NOT X` out. This only works when a complete `X` or `NOT X` is hit by your selection. When you select your six selected cells you will hit the `AD` area completely, but not the `A'D` area. This means you cannot cancel them out and get just `D` as you want to. When you hit the whole `AD` and `A'D` area this has the meaning as: "Well, the condition depends on `D` and is totally unrelated to the value of `A`."

When written as boolean algebra you get:

```
AD OR A'D
(A OR A') AND D
( true  ) AND D
D
```

That would be the goal. But since you don't cover the whole `A'D` area you can't make this simplification here.

To check if you have selected the correct numbers of cell in a selected area, the numbers of cells must be a value of power of 2. So it must be one of 1, 2, 4, 18, 16, ...

In this case you have the regions:

- `A` (2*4=8)
- `BD` (2*2=4)
- `B'C` (2*2=4, notice how the region "wraps" around the edge of the K-map)

Keep in mind that the result for `A'B'C'D` is `false`, not `true`. But when you have just `D` in your boolean algebra like in `A+D+B'C`, the result would be `true`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Not sure if I understood it correctly but this is not covered in the standard K Map rules right? I mean if we ask someone to follow the standard rules of K Maps, then what I did was still legal? Someone with an inner understanding of how K Maps work will only be able to identify it?

Comment: @Dushan No, the six cell region you highlighted was not legal. The "standard rules" say that the region must be of a size of power of 2 and they must form a rectangle.

Comment: Thank you so very much, the book I was referring to only said that quoting "Groups must contain an even number of 1s (2, 4, 6, and so on)" end quoting, which is wrong. And I was very confused. Thank you so very much for clarifying this in great detail. Bless your soul.

Comment: @Dushan Yes, that sentence (I guess it's from the "Cambridge International AS & A Level Computer Science" book?) is wrong.